# Reinstalar servicio con otro nombre

Tags: c#, servicio

Actualmente tengo un servicio ( Servicio 1) de windows funcionando correctamente.
Le he hecho una mejora y lo he llamado Servicio 2 y quiero instalarlo, pero quiero parar primero el Servicio 1 y luego instalar y lanzar el Servicio 2 para ver que si falla parar el Servicio 2 inmediatamente y reiniciar el Servicio 1.

He probado a cambiar todos los ProductCode, el Guid del AssemblyInfo, el nombre, descripcion y demas del Servicio 2.

Sin embargo al instalarlo me salta el error 1001 indicando que ya existe ese servicio...

Alguien podria decirme que tengo que cambiar en el Servicio 2 para que el sistema entienda que es un servicio completamente nuevo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Cómo instalas el servicio?

Comment: Hola @Marc He creado un instalador del tipo "Setup Project"

Comment: El servicio no se instala con el nombre de la clase?

Comment: Si, es que ese es el problema, pensaba que cambiando en el instalador el ProductName, el ProductCode el sistema seria capaz de instalarlo con otro nombre... pero parece que no..., aparte acabo de cambiar el nombre de la clase por si acaso pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo...

Comment: Deberías cambiar la propiedad [ServiceInstaller.ServiceName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Deberías cambiar la propiedad [ServiceInstaller.ServiceName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.servicename(v=vs.110).aspx).
Esta propiedad indica el nombre utilizado por el sistema para identificar este servicio. Esta propiedad debe ser idéntica a la `ServiceBase.ServiceName` del servicio que desea instalar.
Por defecto esta propiedad se encuentra en el método `InitializeComponent` correspondiente en el `Designer.cs` del servicio.
Muestro una captura de pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero me sigue saliendo lo mismo... debo tener alguna otra cosa mal, no lo se :(

Comment: Prueba también a modificar la propiedad `ServiceInstaller.DisplayName`

Answer (score -2):

1001 el servicio ya existe, el la desinstalacion del servicio si se realiza por setup, requiere reinicio de windows. 
Yo uso [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/)

Tiene grandes ventajas:

- Crear un servicio de windows con una aplicación de consola.
- Depurar sin complicaciones de permisos.
- Administrar el servicio por linea de [comandos](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html) (instalación, nombre del servicio, etc..., desinstalación)
- Se integra con loggers mas conocidos , lognet, serilog...

  ```
  public class TownCrier
  {
    readonly Timer _timer;
    public TownCrier()
  {
  _timer = new Timer(1000) {AutoReset = true};
  _timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("It is {0} 
  and all is well", DateTime.Now);
  }
  public void Start() { _timer.Start(); }
  public void Stop() { _timer.Stop(); }
  }

  public class Program
  {
  public static void Main()
  {
  var rc = HostFactory.Run(x =>                                   //1
  {
      x.Service<TownCrier>(s =>                                   //2
      {
         s.ConstructUsing(name=> new TownCrier());                //3
         s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());                         //4
         s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());                          //5
      });
      x.RunAsLocalSystem();                                       //6

      x.SetDescription("Sample Topshelf Host");                   //7
      x.SetDisplayName("Stuff");                                  //8
      x.SetServiceName("Stuff");                                  //9
  });                                                             //10

  var exitCode = (int) Convert.ChangeType(rc, rc.GetTypeCode());  //11
  Environment.ExitCode = exitCode;
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Es muy interesante.. pero esto no responde la pregunta y parece una propaganda...

Comment: Llegado el caso esto deberia ir como comentario

Comment: Se agradece la sugerencia y cuando tenga un rato lo mirare un poco, pero ahora necesitaria hacerlo de la otra manera, para asi tambien aprender porque falla.

Comment: no es propaganda es una librería gratuita, y es la mejor solución para los servicios, modificar un servicio a topself es tan simple como agregar tu servicio al hostfactory

Comment: 1001 el servicio ya existe, el la desinstalacion del servicio si se realiza por setup, requiere reinicio de windows.